# xsd:assert (complicated character verification)

Tags: xpath, xsd-1.1

Is there a way to verify that the template contains only those characters that are passed to @param ?

I considered options with xpath functions(fn:) but have not found a suitable option.

this is 2 valid xml for example:

```
<rule type="myRule" template="A-B-CB">
  <attribute param="B"/>
  <attribute param="A"/>
  <attribute param="C"/>
</rule> 


<rule type="myRule" template="A(C)-B">
  <attribute param="C"/>
  <attribute param="A"/>
  <attribute param="B"/>
</rule>
```

and 2 not valid xml:

```
<rule type="myRule" template="AB-CD">
  <attribute param="A"/>
  <attribute param="B"/>
  <attribute param="C"/>
</rule> 


<rule type="myRule" template="AC">
  <attribute param="A"/>
  <attribute param="B"/>
  <attribute param="C"/>
</rule>
```

perhaps there are ideas how to implement it using schematrone or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the set of letters in `@template` must be exactly the same as the set of letters in `./attribute/@param`?

That is to say, `distinct-values(string-to-codepoints(replace(@template, '\P{L}', '')))` must be the same set as `distinct-values(attribute/@param/string-to-codepoints())`.

So how do you assert that two sequences contain the same values, under permutation?

In XPath 3.1, `deep-equal(sort($X), sort($Y))`

In XPath 2.0, I can't think of anything better than

```
empty($X[not(.=$Y)]) and empty($Y[not(.=$X)])
```

I'll leave you to put this all together.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this solution is ideal for my task. But I can't use it.  I am trying to use this `fn:deep-equal(fn:sort(fn:distinct-values(fn:string-to-codepoints(fn:replace(@template, '\L', '')))), fn:sort(fn:distinct-values(attribute/@param/string-to-codepoints())))` but get this error `Function does not exist: fn:sort arity: 1.`   For function i am use standart namespace xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"> can you help me?

Comment: As I mentioned, fn:sort() requires XPath 3.1 - whether that's available depends on the schema processor you are using. If you can't use 3.1, I gave you a 2.0 alternative.

Comment: Alternative for 2.0 Xpath I can't implement either. I get this error: `Assertion evaluation for element *** on schema type *** did not succeed. FORX0002 - Invalid regular expression.` If i delete regExp i get this error in java: `nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.lang.UCharacter`

Comment: Correcting the regex.

Comment: Oh, now i think regex correct, but i get this error in java: `nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.lang.UCharacter`  `at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.utils.StringCodePointIterator.<init>(StringCodePointIterator.java:35)`same error I got when trying to use the fn:string-length function. What is the problem with using this solution?

Comment: Don't know, but I should raise a new question. ClassNotFoundException suggests a product configuration issue, so raise a question specific to the XPath processor you are using.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as a solution to my problem. Because I like this approach and I think it will work. However, I will have to deal with the error that occurs next. I will be glad if you have any ideas in this regard